# eb deploy does not update the code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an application version but `eb deploy` command fails with:

> ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For
>   more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

I checked the logs, made some changes to the code, committed and deployed again and guess what, it failed again. The logs indicate the same error, disregarding my changes. The error occurs in a file in this directory `/var/app/ondeck/app/`, when I go check, I can see the previous version is there.

I tried deploying using the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard, but somehow the instance is not receiving the new version. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: can you post the logs which have the said errors.

Comment: I changed the AMI to the latest and the problem is gone. Also the logs I guess :)

Answer (score 65):

Just had the same problem and noticed in the documentation

"Note
If you have initialized a git repository in your project folder, the EB CLI will always deploy the latest commit, even if you have pending changes. Commit your changes prior to running eb deploy to deploy them to your environment."

made the commits and worked fine

Comment: Or you can use the `--staged` flag to deploy uncommitted changes too.

Comment: this could actually 2 hours of my time if they've said that in the quickstart guide for django app deployment

Comment: Oh lordy. Thanks ;)

Comment: remember to type *git add <file>* or *git add .* to actually stage (without committing) your files. only then will *eb deploy --staged* pick them up

Comment: This is unintuitive. I want to deploy to my test environment before I even stage anything